# Wordpress loop not working on static front page

Tags: posts, loop, query, frontpage

I have a static wordpress front page. I want the code that works on my regular blog template to work on the homepage too.
Currently, it only shows one post. The code in the main index.php is this...

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

content.php calls this....

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- /col-md-4 -->
```

This works great while on the blog page. But i can't get this exact same content on to the static home page. I know I need a different query for homepage but no idea what that is. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What WordPress template are you putting this code into? Have you set a frontpage under `Settings -> Reading` ?

Answer (score 1):

The loop in a page loads only the content of the page. Thus you see only one post.

You have to set up a "Page of Posts". You can find basic examples in the codex at [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template). But using it as static front page results in some problems. The links to follow pages will not work. You have to evaluate `get_query_var('page')` instead of `get_query_var('paged')`.

There are also some plugins, but I don't think that they solve the problems with a static front page:

- Posts in Page
- Powerful Posts Per Page
- Add Posts to Pages